# Как изменить стандартную иконку геопозиции плользователя yandex maps?

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

[image: Образец]

Нужно изменить эту иконку на другую. Как изменять плейсмарки я знаю. Но с позицией юзера это не работает.
Пишу на react js с использованием react-yandex-maps библиотеки.

Comment: А в реакте есть какая-то проблема создавать метку вручную по кастомной кнопке, определяющей геолокацию пользователя? Отключить штатную иконку и добавить свою. В доке Яндекса такой пример есть, например https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.GeolocationControl.html

Answer (score 1):

Вот мой пример

```
function getYaMap(){
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [**координаты**],
            zoom: 17
        }),

        // Создаём макет содержимого.
        MyIconContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
            '<div style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold;">$[properties.iconContent]</div>'
        ),

        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
            hintContent: '**Название**'
        }, {
            // Опции.
            // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
            iconLayout: 'default#image',
            // Своё изображение иконки метки.
            iconImageHref: '**ссылка на иконку**',
            // Размеры метки.
            iconImageSize: [42, 42],
            // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
            // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
            iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
        });

    myMap.geoObjects
        .add(myPlacemark)
}
```